# Check GPU OpenGL Limits

Tags: opengl, gpu

I was wondering if there is an easy way to query (programatically) the GPU OpenGL Limits for the following features:
- maximum 2D texture size
- maximum 3D texture size
- maximum number of vertex shader attributes
- maximum number of varying floats
- number of texture image units (in vertex shader, and in fragment shader)
- maximum number of draw buffers

I need to know these numbers in advance before writing my GPU Research Project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[glGet()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) is your friend, with:

- `GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE`
- `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`
- `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`
- `GL_MAX_VARYING_FLOATS`
- `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS`
- `GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS`

e.g.:

```
GLint result;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VARYING_FLOATS, &result);
```

Not quite sure what your project is setting out to achieve, but you might be interested in [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) if it's general purpose computing and you weren't already aware of it. In particular [Cl/GL interop](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/opencl/sdk/website/Graphics_Interop.html) if there is a graphics element too and your hardware supports it.

As Damon pointed out in the comments in practice it may be more complex than this for texture sizes. The problems arise because rendering may fallback from hardware to software for some sizes of textures, and also because the size of a texture varies depending upon the pixel format used. To work around this it is possible to use [GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_* with glTexImage*](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/texture.htm#text0120).

Comment: Thanks awoodland ! I believe that I'll also need to learn OpenCL. Haven't used it before, but that would be handy to learn that.

Comment: Note that while the sizes returned by GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE will usually work, they are merely hints and not guaranteed for every pixel format. According to the OpenGL FAQ (21.130), it is perfectly legal for an implementation to report a size greater than what the hardware can handle, as long as it can somehow make it work correctly (in software). So, to be on the 100% safe side, they recommend one uses glTexImage2D with GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D.

Comment: @Damon - good point, my answer was just introducing glGet (since that seemed to be the knowledge the OP was looking for). I'll update my answer to be more general for the textures.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to what was said by "awoodland" and if you still do not know ... i think you should take a look at GLEW...

GLEW provides efficient run-time mechanisms for determining which OpenGL extensions are supported on the target platform.

http://glew.sourceforge.net/