# Get max texture size in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to get the width and height of the maximum texture size supported by the GPU powering the app? How can I get this information in Visual C++ (VS2012)?

Comment: This answer would appear to be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003813/check-gpu-opengl-limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. D3D9 in my case, so not OpenGL (sorry for not clarifying this).

```
...
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3d9caps.h>

int mw, mh;
...
void CheckMaxTextureSize()
{
    IDirect3D9* d3d9;
    D3DCAPS9 caps;
    d3d9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    d3d9->GetDeviceCaps(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, &caps);
    mw = caps.MaxTextureWidth;
    mh = caps.MaxTextureHeight;
}
```

you may also want to terminate it (but not in my case).